# Why we need `django-webpack-looader` to serve Vue SPA application through django?

Tags: django, vue.js, webpack, single-page-application, django-webpack-loader

I want to serve my Vue application (as SPA) through django, and I passed across this [article](https://medium.com/@rodrigosmaniotto/integrating-django-and-vuejs-with-vue-cli-3-and-webpack-loader-145c3b98501a). The author use `django-webpack-loader` to achieve this, but is not adding a simple `TemplateView` around `dist/index.html` will do the job:

```
url(r'^app/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='app'),
```

also this require altering `settings.by` as follow:

```
'DIRS': [
    BASE_DIR + "/templates/",
    BASE_DIR + "/dist/",
]
```

My question is what is the role of `django-webpack-loader` in the process if the app is already build using `vue-cli`?

Answer (score 0):

After trying my approach without `django-webpack-loader`, I concluded that after each build, you have to do the following:

1. Put your entry-point (`index.html`), in a place that django can find it.
2. Put your assets (*css, js, images*) in the `static` folder.
3. Edit your `index.html` so it can correctly locate and load the scripts and css files, e.g:

> ```
> <script src=/js/chunk-vendors.618e754e.js></script>
> <script src=/js/app.bbfdaab6.js></script>
> ```

Should be:

> ```
> <script src="{% static 'js/app.bbfdaab6.js' %}"></script>
> <script src="{% static 'js/chunk-vendors.618e754e.js' %}"></script>
> ```

So `django-webpack-loader` should helps you with automating this task. without going through django `staticfiles` system.

Also I have read that `django-webpack-loader` can provide hot-code reloading during development but I did not try this out. Also I could not find information on how `django-webpack-loader` works really, so consider this answer incomplete.